# DocC documentation archive not recognised by Xcode in a CocoaPod

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, docc

While developing the internal project for a CocoaPod, I can successfully add a `.docc` documentation archive, build documentation and see the changes reflected in the Xcode documentation viewer. However, when I include the pod in another project (and run `pod install`), the documentation archive is treated as a normal folder and its customisations are not reflected when building documentation. From the icon, it looks like Xcode does not recognise it:

| The pod's internal project directory | The pod's directory inside the project that installed it |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Xcode directory list with "DoccDemo.docc" folder displaying a special bookshelf icon.] | [image: Xcode directory list with "DoccDemo.docc" folder displaying standard folder icon.] |

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Cocoapods does not currently support DocC and will incorrectly build the pods project, treating the `.docc` directory as a normal folder. [A fix has been submitted](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/10888) and looks like it will be included in the next version (1.12.0).

Edit: [Version 1.12.0](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.12.0) has been released including the fix for this issue!